# How to fix renamed Input "file" browse button not working on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used this code for rename input type file browse button, that code working on Firefox and chrome, but it doesn't work on IE 8 +, **Can someone please help me to fix this or please give me a alternative way to do this**, thank you

**HTML**

```
    <input type="button" class="red" id="pseudobutton" value="Attach Photo"/>
    <input type="file" name="attachement" class="hide" id="openssme" onmousedown="buttonPush('depressed');" onmouseup="buttonPush('normal');" onmouseout="buttonPush('phased');"/>
```

**CSS**

```
   input.hide
    {
          position:absolute;
          left:370px;
          -moz-opacity:0;
          filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
          opacity: 0;
          z-index: 2;
    }
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonPush (buttonStatus)
  {
  if (buttonStatus == "depressed")
        document.getElementById("pseudobutton").style.borderStyle = "inset";
  else
        document.getElementById("pseudobutton").style.borderStyle = "outset";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: do you have a `<form>` Tag in your HTML? IE is picky about that ...

Comment: @AxelAmthor of course this is only part of html form

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't work on IE 8? or all IE versions above 8?

Comment: Set up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c28c1pwr/). How can an invisible element get a click event? You might click it, but as long as opacity is 0, it's quite hard to find the button ...

Comment: @AxelAmthor 's fiddle works in IE 11 for me once I fix the alignment. http://jsfiddle.net/7a0j8u0m/